# Multivariate forecasting with R (package MTS and portes)

Tags: r

I'm trying to simulate a vector/multivariate ARMA process and forecast it.

I know i can simulate with *VARMAsim* (in package MTS) or *varima.sim* (in package portes). Say i simulate a VARMA Z = (Z1, Z2) with length n = 300. Stationary and Invertibility can be checked with invertQ (in package portes).

With the function *VARMA* (in package MTS) i can fit the simulated data Z using VARMA model. The output gives me "AR coefficient matrix" and "MA coefficient matrix" and also aic and bic.

My questions are:

1. How can i choose the order **p** and **q**, which the function VARMA need for the fitting?
2. In the univariate case we have the function ***predict(object, n.ahead, ...)*** to predict the future values. Which function do that in the multivariate case?

Thank you

**Edit**:

1. Choosing AR and MA order

In the package MTS i find the function Eccm (Extended Cross-Correlation Matrices), which can be used to identify AR and MA order. The function gives us the p-values of multivariate Ljung-Box statistics of a vector time series.

```
Eccm(zt, maxp = 5, maxq = 6, include.mean = FALSE, rev = TRUE)
```

But i don't know how can i choose a p-value from the output table? For example i have the following table (sorry i dont know how to make a table):

p-values table of Extended Cross-correlation Matrices: 
Column: MA order 
Row   : AR order 
       **-------- 0 -------- 1 ------- 2 ------- 3 ------ 4 ------ 5 ------ 6**    
**0 ---**    0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
**1 ---**    0.0000 0.6159 0.8570 0.9127 0.7225 0.4764 0.7629 
**2 ---**   0.3262 0.6724 0.8356 0.1448 0.2728 0.9801 0.9848 
**3 ---**    0.9180 0.9882 0.4939 0.4119 0.8937 0.9934 0.9984 
**4 ---**    0.9473 0.9340 0.8216 0.9739 0.9864 0.9996 0.9962 
**5 ---**    0.9861 0.9331 0.9983 1.0000 0.9937 0.9802 0.9934

Which one should i take? And why?

2. In the same package (MTS) i found the function VARMApred(...), which should be the multivariate version of predict function we have above.

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer but, have you tried topepo?
http://topepo.github.io/caret/Multivariate_Adaptive_Regression_Splines.html

Answer (score 0):

If you read the reference suggested in the MTS help file, ch 3 of Tsay, the VARMA order should be the top left vertex of the non-zero values in the eccm table.

i.e. the table suggests a VARMA(1,1) model.